# Grafana + Zabbix: Filter Host multiple host group

Tags: regex, grafana, zabbix

I have installed Grafana and integrated into my zabbix server.
I need to filter host groups so they don't contain any of the specified groups.

In zabbix a host corresponds to several groups, in grafana I want them not to be displayed if they belong to at least one specified group.

I tried with the regex: `/^((?!INTERNET).)*$/`

But if a host also has other group than the INTERNET it is displayed

Comment: can you please write what is the input and what should be desired output?

Comment: Input is: "SERVER, INTERNET". If INTERNET is present it must be filtered

Comment: Hello. Did you ever managed to solve this? I am also having the same problem to filter hosts based on multiple groups (Without OR operator...).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
 (?:INTERNET)
```

Comment: This filter all elements in list

Comment: which elements? please provide more details so you can receive help

Comment: ELEMENT 1: NAME: TEST, GROUP: INTERNET, SERVER, ELEMENT 2: NAME: TEST 2, GROUP: SERVER. Element 1 should be removed. With  (?:INTERNET) also element 2 is removed

Comment: I'm confused about what your input is, in the previous comment you posted string, and now this seems like it is an array if you post a question here, be sure that provide a good explanation of what you need, the current situation is confusing and no one can help you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what zabbix plug-in in grafana return array or a string. In the Problem table I see a column in format "group 1, group 2". In the query inspector I see an array of groups so I'm not sure how grafana query manage this filter